# Find clock time, given lines of hands

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, matlab, angle

I have a clock, and two hands for minutes and hours.

- Clock is centered somewhere around (165, -163)

I have two lines, represented by two points each. To be specific:

- (51, -143) and (173, -158) for the minutes hand.
- (198, -91) and (159, -165) for the hours hand.

The image looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZuWi.png

Now, I need to calculate the time given this information. How should I go about it?

Small note: I am using matlab, and y-coordinates are actually written positively.

Comment: Do you know how to find the equation of a line passing through two points?

Comment: @TobyMak Yes, calculate m = (y2-y1) / (x2-x1) and then find n by substituting a point into y=mx + n

Comment: Hint: what are the slopes of the hand lines? Do you know how to convert slopes to angles?

Comment: @PM2Ring That's where I am stuck at. I know by heart that for example if m = 1 then angle between the axes and line is 45, but how to actually convert them?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know matlab, but you should have an arctan function that converts slopes to angles. Ideally, there's a function that allows you to pass the $y$ and $x$ deltas separately, so it can get the correct quadrant and handle vertical lines. In C and related languages you'd do `atan2(delta_y, delta_x)`. Normally, such a function returns the angle in radians, but you may also have a form that returns degrees, so check your documentation carefully.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Here is how much the hour hand travels per hour, minute, second:

> - Per Hour:
>     $$\text{H}=\frac{360^{\circ}}{12\space\text{hours}}=30^{\circ}\text{/}\space\text{hour}$$
> - Per Minute:
>     $$\text{M}=\frac{\text{H}^{\circ}}{60\space\text{minutes}}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\circ}\text{/}\space\text{minute}$$
> - Per Second:
>     $$\text{S}=\frac{\text{M}^{\circ}}{60\space\text{seconds}}=\left(\frac{1}{120}\right)^{\circ}\text{/}\space\text{second}$$